# Is there a library that does array equivalency for numpy.ma?

Tags: python, numpy, masking

There is a numpy.testing package for comparing numpy arrays, but there doesn't appear to be an equivalent for masked arrays. Is there a library out there that does this already?

I notice that numpy.ma itself has some comparison functions like numpy.ma.allequal, but this function doesn't seem to check that both array masks are identical. E.g. -

```
In [151]: a = ma.masked_array([0,1,2,3],[True,False,False,False])

In [152]: b = ma.masked_array([0,1,2,3],[True,True,False,False])

In [153]: ma.allequal(a,b)
Out[153]: True
```

Comment: `numpy.testing` isn't for comparing numpy arrays; everything comparison-related in there is an assert method completely inappropriate for general-purpose array comparisons.

Comment: What comparison semantics do you want, anyway? You want equal masks, apparently. Do you want equal fillvalues? Exactly equal elements, or up to a tolerance? Identical dtypes? Identical memory layout? If a cell is masked in both masked arrays, do the masked-out values in the data arrays matter?

Answer (score 1):

`ma.masked_array.__eq__` is actually implemented in numpy, but maybe it does not have the semantics you are looking for? You can get to the documentation with `help(ma.masked_array.__eq__)` with a python interpreter, it states:

> Check whether other equals self elementwise

Which is what I can see given your example: it does the comparison where the data is marked as valid, and returns the result in the data field of a masked array. Wherever the data was invalid (for a or b) the resulting masked array field is masked.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import numpy.ma as ma
>>> a = ma.masked_array([0,1,2,3],[True,False,False,False])
>>> b = ma.masked_array([0,1,2,3],[True,True,False,False])
>>> a==b
masked_array(data = [-- -- True True],
             mask = [ True  True False False],
       fill_value = True)
>>> b = ma.masked_array([0,1,2,4],[True,True,False,False])
>>> a==b
masked_array(data = [-- -- True False],
             mask = [ True  True False False],
       fill_value = True)
```

If you want to **check that all the fields are valid and equal** you could use:

<strike>np.allfalse((a==b).data)</strike>

edit: actually, I think you would need:

```
not np.any((a==b).mask) and np.alltrue((a==b).compressed())
```

If you want to **check that all the valid fields are equal** you could use:

```
np.alltrue((a==b).compressed())
```

As user2357112 explained in the comment, `numpy.testing` provides functions for unit testing on numpy arrays, which might not be what you are looking for. It it is, you could still use the regular `assert` function with the examples that I provided.